# Как разрешить доступ конкретным пользователям к методу контроллера, если у них нет нужной роли?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Есть атрибут авторизации который фильтрует пользователей по ролям. Как предоставить доступ к методу контроллера определенным пользователям с определёнными Email, если у них нет нужной роли.
Есть аттрибут:
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.CompanyOwner)]
А есть пару менеджеров, которым в качестве исключения необходимо предоставить доступ к функциям используя их Email?

Comment: Ролевой доступ подразумевает, что есть роль и что в неё включают доступ. Либо вы даёте доступ этим менеджерам доступ к готовой роли, либо если она не подходит (слишком много даёт доступа) -- нужно создать отдельную роль. Это штатный способ. Да, никому не нравится, когда у них в Active Directory или приложении сотни ролей для доступа, но поверьте все эти "в виде исключения" -- это просто дорога в ад по сравнению с рекомендованным подходом. Документируйте, создавайте kb для администраторов, но вот эти костыли и хаки - это зло.

Comment: И кажись, уже выпилили даже [доступ по пользователям](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/8.3.php) через указание логинов `[Authorize (Users="Ivanov, Petrov")]`, в офдоках уже нет примера, проверьте свою версию .net. Технически можно наверное свой кастомный аттрибут создать на базе AuthorizeAttribute - но я бы рекомендовал оформить нормально роль.